# How to avoid being friends multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, rails-activerecord

I am stuck with the friendships model. I can be friends with an user multiple times. So I need a condition to avoid add to friend link .
My users_controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
        @users = User.all
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @topics = @user.topics.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @friendship = @user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    @friendships = @user.friendships.all

  end
```

my show.html.erb:

```
       <section>
            <h1><%= @user.username %></h1>     
       <%= link_to "Arkadaşlarıma Ekle", friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

            </section>
```

my friendships_controller :

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
        if @friendship.save
            flash[:notice] = "Arkadaşlara eklendi."
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            flash[:error] = "Arkadaşlara Eklenemiyor."
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @friendship = current_user.friendships.find(params[:id])
        @friendship.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Arkadaşlarımdan kaldırıldı."
        redirect_to current_user
    end
end
```

so I guess , I tried add this   method  in users_controller but still no solution for it. Can you help me to fix it?

```
def friend?(other_user)
   friendships.find_by_friend_id(other_user.id)
 end
```

and In before link

```
<% unless friend?(@user) %>
%= link_to "Arkadaşlarıma Ekle", friendships_path(:friend_id => @user), :method => :post,class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<%end %>
```

My user model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :topics
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
    has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
    has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
end
```

my Friendship model :

```
    class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id
      belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
    validates :friend, :presence => true, :unless => :friend_is_self

def friend_is_self
  user_id == friend_id ? false : true
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is best to do such validations on the model level. use [validate_uniqueness_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) in your model and test for validity in your controller.

Comment: Shall i use it in user or friendships model.

Comment: probably on the friendship model. you should validate uniqueness of a given user in the scope of another user.

Comment: Yes. I think this should do it.

Comment: so in the view ..how can i test them if they are friends?Can you check my last edit. I did the current_user test but not for the friends test.

Comment: the line `if @friendship.save` should also validate. you will get the error in the errors and display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Your `friend?` method is returning the `friendship` or `nil`, not `true` or `false` as you would expect with a `?` method.

Try

```
def friend?(other_user)
  # this assumes Friendship is a user, which probably isn't true
  # but I don't have your models but this should give you the right idea
  self.friendships.include other_user
end
```

Comment: I get synthax error unexpected ':' expecting keyword end and it shows the error in the space before false

Comment: Actually it doesn't really matter since in ruby `nil` is evaluated to `false` in boolean context and friendship will evaluate to `true`

Comment: Actually the site fails to work in that way ? I could not find a way already.

Answer (score 0):

I think the friend? method should be something similar as:

```
def friend?(other_user)
   current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(other_user.id)
end
```

since I guess friendship should be a table with user_id and friend_id, what we want to check is if this user has othter_user as a friend or not.

Comment: What is your suggestion about view. I get undefined method for 'friend?'